# Can I get sound data as array?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I'm making program for **Active Noise Control**(also use *Adaptive* instead of Active / use *Cancellation* instead of Control)

System is pretty simple.

1. get sound via mic
2. turn the sound into data, which I can read(Something like **Integer array**)
3. make antiphase of the sound.
4. turn the data into sound file

Follwing is my question

1. Can I read sound as Integer Array?
2. If I can use Integer Array, how can I make antiphase? Just multiply -1 to every data?
3. Any useful think about my project
4. Is there any recommended language rather than java?

I heard that stackoverflow have many top class programmers. So, I expect for critical answer :D

Comment: I think you are going to need PCM data (which I believe is all Java handles natively anyway).  One problem here is the fact that the length of the frame will often times be _more_ than a single byte (i.e. 16 bit sound which means the frame length is 2 bytes).  I'm not sure what you mean by anti-phase, but if it's just negating the sound wave (i.e. reflecting it by the "y-axis") then you need to read the bytes from the frame length and create the negative from the frame...which will mean bit operations and worrying about big endian vs. little endian.

Comment: ^You also need to worry about signed vs. unsigned PCM and a working knowledge of 2's complement to do the correct conversions.

Comment: "What have you done so far?"

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao While capturing data is a _very_ small part of this question, it doesn't help at all about how to change the actual audio data which seems to be the main question here.

Comment: I have a couple of projects (of my own) on synthesizing audio data (i.e. generating PCM data--one example is generating a simple sinusoidal wave).  I think that might be helpful, but it requires _a lot_ of bitwise operations and two's complement to understand and handle the various `AudioFormat` types (and that's _just_ dealing with PCM data--I have nothing on handling more complicated formats like MP3 etc.).  It would help if you would specify a _specific_ `AudioFormat`: give the sample rate, sample size (in bits), number of channels, signed or unsigned PCM, and little or big endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions:

(1) When you read sound, a byte array is returned. The bytes can readily be decoded into integers, shorts, floats, whatever. Java supports many common formats, and probably has one that matches your microphone input and speaker output. For example, Java supports 16-bit encoding, stereo, 44100 fps, which is considered the standard for CD-quality. There are several questions already at StackOverflow that show the coding for the decoding and recoding back to bytes.

(2) Yes, just multiply by -1 to every element of your PCM array. When you add the negative to the correctly lined up counterpart, 0 will result.

(3 & 4) I don't know what the tolerances are for lag time! I think if you simply take the input, decode, multiply by -1, recode, and output, it might be possible to get a *very* small amount of processing time. I don't know what Java is capable of here, but I bet it will be on the scale of a dozen millis, give or take. How much is enough for cancellation? How far does the sound travel from mike to speaker location? How much time does that allow? (Or am I missing something about how this works? I haven't done this sort of thing before.)

Java is pretty darn fast, and you will be relatively close to the native code level with the reading and writing and simple numeric conversions. The core code (for testing) could probably be written in an afternoon, using the following tutorial examples as a template: [Reading/Writing sound files, see code snippets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html). I'd pay particular attention to the spot where the comment reads "Here do something useful with the audio data that is in the bytes array..." At this point,
you would put the code to convert the bytes to DSP, multiply by -1, then convert back to bytes.

If Java doesn't prove fast enough, I assume the next thing to try would be some flavor of C.